# Value overrided after round played, visible when printed out

Tags: python

**My code:**

```
users = []
users.append({"name" : "",
              "numerics" : [],
              "score" : 0 })
users[0]["name"] = input("Your name plz: ")

def getNumbers():
    for i in range(len(users)):
        numbers = input("Assign 8 different numbers (separate each with a comma ','): ")
        userNumbers = numbers.split(",")
    return userNumbers

users[0]["numerics"] = getNumbers()

scores = []
scores.append(users[:])
print(scores)

users[0]["numerics"] = getNumbers()
scores.append(users[:])

print(scores)
```

**Running example:**

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> users = []
>>> users.append({"name" : "",
              "numerics" : [],
              "score" : 0 })
>>> users[0]["name"] = input("Your name plz: ")
Your name plz: Gladiator
>>> def getNumbers():
    for i in range(len(users)):
        numbers = input("Assign 8 different numbers (separate each with a comma ','): ")
        userNumbers = numbers.split(",")
    return userNumbers

>>> users[0]["numerics"] = getNumbers()
Assign 8 different numbers (separate each with a comma ','): 99,23,55,11,19,100,1000,89
>>> scores = []
>>> scores.append(users[:])
>>> print(scores)
[[{'numerics': ['99', '23', '55', '11', '19', '100', '1000', '89'], 'name': 'Gladiator', 'score': 0}]]
>>> users[0]["numerics"] = getNumbers()
Assign 8 different numbers (separate each with a comma ','): 100,56,77,32,99,22,45,2
>>> scores.append(users[:])
>>> print(scores)
[[{'numerics': ['100', '56', '77', '32', '99', '22', '45', '2'], 'name': 'Gladiator', 'score': 0}], [{'numerics': ['100', '56', '77', '32', '99', '22', '45', '2'], 'name': 'Gladiator', 'score': 0}]]
>>>
```

I want to be able to for each new round in the game, make changes to the user **numerics** and score, and append it to the **score** list and then print that out. However, it seems like my current way is just overriding the **numerics** and the **score**. **But mostly the numerics part.**

This doesn't seem to work at all: `users[0]["score"].append(getNumbers())`
Or should I simply clear the values in the list, e.g. score and numerics for each new round for the player.

```
Round 1: 
Player: Gladiator
Numerics: ['99', '23', '55', '11', '19', '100', '1000', '89']

Round 2: 
Player: Gladiator
Numerics: ['100', '56', '77', '32', '99', '22', '45', '2']
```

**But the print out shows:**

```
[[{'numerics': ['100', '56', '77', '32', '99', '22', '45', '2'], 
'name': 'Gladiator', 'score': 0}], 

[{'numerics': ['100', '56', '77', '32', '99', '22', '45', '2'], 
'name': 'Gladiator', 'score': 0}]]
```

**EDIT: I tried resetting the list of numerics:**

```
 users[0]['numerics'] = []
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

**Test ran the code example by @Sarathsp**

```
Your name plz: Gladiator
Assign 8 different numbers (separate each with a comma ','): 99,100,1000,4,66,77,11,9
[[{'name': 'Gladiator', 'numerics': ['99', '100', '1000', '4', '66', '77', '11', '9'], 'score': 0}]]
Assign 8 different numbers (separate each with a comma ','): 100,33,44,55,0,1,9,2
[[{'name': 'Gladiator', 'numerics': ['99', '100', '1000', '4', '66', '77', '11', '9'], 'score': 0}], [{'name': 'Gladiator', 'numerics': ['100', '33', '44', '55', '0', '1', '9', '2'], 'score': 0}]]
```

Comment: What would you like to be the score field after running the program? I don't see in the code any calculation of it

Comment: Well, if Gladiator, got the correct numerics, the score should increase, based on the number of correct numerics guessed. But in the next round, everything should reset and then the score should be based on that new round played.

Comment: `users[0]["score"].append(getNumbers())` doesn't work because `users[0]["score"]` is an integer, not a list. Declare it as a list if you want to append a new value

Comment: @Jalo, probably not needed, because a list for score is simply not needed. But what do you think? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the score field is an integer, keep it that way. At the end of the round, you can calculate the score and replace the dictionary value  before printing it e.g. `users[0]["score"] = your_score`

Comment: @Jalo, `users[0]["score"]`, **ignore that one**. Can you explain why the `users[0]['numerics']`  part is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. You have to use `deep copy` to copy the `users` list

there is a module `copy` 
you may use it as

```
copy.deepcopy(users)
```

Here is how your program look like

```
import copy
users = []
users.append({"name" : "",
              "numerics" : [],
              "score" : 0 })
users[0]["name"] = input("Your name plz: ")

def getNumbers():
    for i in range(len(users)):
        numbers = input("Assign 8 different numbers (separate each with a comma ','): ")
        userNumbers = numbers.split(",")
    return userNumbers

users[0]["numerics"] = getNumbers()

scores = []
scores.append(copy.deepcopy(users))
print(scores)

users[0]["numerics"] = getNumbers()
scores.append(copy.deepcopy(users))

print(scores)
```

Comment: Hi, I will try this now and report back to you. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have tried this on python3 and is working fine, please accept the answer and upvote if it helps  you

Comment: BIG THANKS! YOU SAVED ME A TON OF TIME.

Comment: Awesome , glad that you got it fixed